# delete data from database in laravel

Tags: laravel

I need to make a project that get an email by using queue in laravel,it tooks an email but I want to delete a user who in the queue after 5 min
this is my controller

```
    public function index(){
    return view()->make("home.index");
}
public function send( Request $request){
    Log::info("Request cycle without Queues started");
      $this->dispatch(new SendWelcomeEmail());
      Log::info("Request cycle without Queues ends");
```

this is my User table

```
 Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('namemail');
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

how could I delete the user after 5min?

Answer (score 0):

I would make another Job something like DeleteUser($user_id) which accept parameter in constructor, then you have to write some logic in Job in handle() method

```
User::find($user_id)->delete();
```

and then you can just call the Job

```
DeleteUser::dispatch($user->id)
            ->delay(now()->addMinutes(5));
```

Also look in the docs https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queues, there is everything you should need.